# Qt: Phonon example code crash on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, phonon

I tried to run the phonon example code, Music player Example, came with the sdk. It runs well on Windows, but crashes while starting on Mac OS Snow Leopard 10.6.8. This is the crash details:

**crash line:**

```
audioOutput = new Phonon::AudioOutput(Phonon::MusicCategory, this);
```

**crash log and call stack:**

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0×0000000000000008
Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 QtCore 0×0000000100e9c8f2 QObject::moveToThread(QThread*) + 34
1 QtDBus 0×00000001010b4912 _q_sessionBus() + 162
2 QtDBus 0×00000001010b4a71 QDBusConnection::sessionBus() + 17
3 phonon 0×000000010001beab Phonon::FactoryPrivate::FactoryPrivate() + 219
4 phonon 0×000000010001edc2 Phonon::Factory::registerFrontendObject(Phonon::MediaNodePrivate*) + 146
5 phonon 0×0000000100028f92 Phonon::MediaNodePrivate::MediaNodePrivate(Phonon::MediaNodePrivate::CastId) + 82
6 phonon 0×00000001000137bf Phonon::AudioOutput::AudioOutput(Phonon::Category, QObject*) + 63
7 com.yourcompany.qmusicplayer 0×00000001000026cc MainWindow::MainWindow() + 108
8 com.yourcompany.qmusicplayer 0×00000001000024a2 main + 114
9 com.yourcompany.qmusicplayer 0×0000000100002404 start + 52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this was a problem with Qt 4.8.0. It required dbus to be installed on your machine.  There are workarounds like installing dbus on your machine or rebuilding Qt with a patch, but I believe it's fixed in Qt 4.8.1 so probably just use that.